# Performance of an SQL query for finding users in database

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an application and I am using Spring Data JPA for database manipulation.

I am implementing a feature for finding friends with a searchbar. The way it is supposed to work is that when you enter some characters, a search is performed in the database to find and display 10 users that match the characters (the first name starts with it, the last name starts with it and it also should work if someone enters the full name).

I have written the code and it works the following way:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value="SELECT * FROM users u WHERE (" +
                "UPPER(first_name) like CONCAT(UPPER(:query),'%') OR " +
                "UPPER(last_name) like CONCAT(UPPER(:query),'%') OR " +
                "UPPER(CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name)) like CONCAT(UPPER(:query),'%')" +
                ") LIMIT 10")
List<User> findByQueryLikeName(@Param("query") String query);
```

However, when I look at this query it really seems like it might not be the best performance-wise. I do not have a lot of knowledge about sql performance, but I think that because it combines 3 where statements with an `OR` operator, and also uses some functions like `UPPER` and `CONCAT` a lot. I am using PostgreSQL.

Can you please assess if this kind of query is going to perform well on a big number of records? Can you try and explain why / why not? Do you have any tips on how to improve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The concatenation of the first and last name would preclude any chance of your SQL using an index.  But, even before this, wrapping the columns in `UPPER` would also probably make using an index not possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: unless you create an index with that expression.

Comment: Postgres' [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) might be something to look at. Or [trigram indexes](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html)

Comment: Yeah, you'd need three indexes, one for each expression, and then you can hope for a `BitmapOr`. It is quite a terrible query though.

Comment: the point of upper is to make the search case-insensitive. the point of concatenation was to enable searching with first name and last name. For example for Adam Smith, i want to have a match for a query like 'Adam Smi' for example. Can you suggest how can I improve on my SQL query so I can use indexes and still have these features?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Full text search won't get you anywhere with substring matching. Trigram indexes are good, but you'd have to rewrite the query.

Comment: I haven't worked with postgre but normally you handle case insensitive using collation on the database or table column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments it's probably so slow because you are using functions in the WHERE clause:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/

Alternatively you could add to your entity another field `fullName` and update it in `setFirstName()` and `setLastName()` like this:

```
void setFirstName(String first){
 this.fullName = first.toUpperCase() + " " + this.lastName.toUpperCase(); //TODO handle nulls
}
```

Then you could query by that `fullName`, which would be already uppercased, then uppercase you search string in java and have a simple like query:

`public List<User> findByFullnameContaining(String searchText, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: thanks, I ended up using this solution. I added a column in my table just for searching, where i concat and uppercase the first and last name. It might be data duplication in the table, but it makes indexing super-easy

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE concat(' ', u.first_name,' ', u.last_name) ILIKE ' ' || :query || '%';
```

You'd have to create a trigram index to support this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON users USING gin
   (concat(' ', u.first_name,' ', u.last_name) gin_trgm_ops);
```